# I downloaded file from webview in zip format but not able to open it in Android

Tags: android

```
 mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

                    request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                    //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
                    String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                    request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                    //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
                    request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                    request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
                    request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    dm.enqueue(request);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

I am able to download the file in zip format but not able to open it.Can any one help me to find out what is the exact issue?

Comment: Are you opening it in your phone (by tapping on download file) or in your application (using some Java code you did not post)?

Comment: Debug your code, what is the value of `mimeType` in that context?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. In fact, in my case, the downloaded zip file is much bigger than the original file.